# enclapsulated embedded variable Array php

Tags: php, arrays, variables

i have a little problem with my code. I'm trying to stamp a variable with and encapsuled array inside into a table row but i don't undestand what i'm doing wrong. Could you help me please?  "indice.php" has an array inside, and down of this i have my correct variable:

```
<?php
include("indice.php");

$indice1 = array_column($indice, Null, "id");

              echo $indice1['1042']['def'];
?>
```

$indice1['1042']['def'] stamps correctly "AFC Bournemouth" on the page. This was only to check the correct functioning of my array, and it is ok.

Few rows down i need to obtain the same result obtaining 1042 with a database calling which ends to $array24[$nuovariga][4], which returns me exactly the 1042 number, that i need to encapsule into the other one array to obtain "AFC Bournemouth". In my table i have many difficult to perform my array!

```
      <tr>
        <td style="width:10%;border: 1px solid black"><b><?php echo $array24[$nuovariga][0]; ?></b></td>
        <td style="width:50%;border: 1px solid black"><b><?php echo $$array24[$nuovariga][1] . " " . $array24[$nuovariga][2]  . " " .  $array24[$nuovariga][3]; ?></b></td>
        <td style="width:10%;border: 1px solid black"><b><?php echo ${"indice1" . "['" . $array24[$nuovariga][4] . "']['def']"}; ?></b></td>
         <td style="width:20%;border: 1px solid black"><b><?php echo $array24[$nuovariga][5]; ?></b></td>
        <td style="width:10%;border: 1px solid black"><b><?php echo $array24[$nuovariga][6]; ?></b></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
```

What am i doing wrong? Without ${ and } it returns exactly "indice1['1054']['def']".... Please, help me :( TY

Comment: Can you share a snippet of your array please

Comment: sure! my array in "indice.php" is

$indice = array(
  array('id' => '1042','def' => 'AFC Bournemouth'),
  array('id' => '1043','def' => 'Brighton & Hove Albion'),
  array('id' => '1044','def' => 'FC Burnley'),
  array('id' => '1045','def' => 'Cardiff City'),
...etc...

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
array_column($indice, 'id');
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Nothing has changed, but Thank you anyway :)